# Como mudar o estado de um ToggleButton em java?

Tags: java, android

Criei  este Drawable para definir como *Background* dos 6 *ToggleButton*.

Como consigo fazer os *ToggleButton* alternar entre eles sem serem clicados?

```
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <item android:state_checked="false" android:state_enabled="true" android:drawable="@drawable/cinquenta" /> 

    <item android:state_checked="true" android:state_enabled="true" android:drawable="@drawable/cinquentaum" />

    <item android:state_enabled="false" android:drawable="@drawable/cinquentadois" />
</selector>
```

```
<LinearLayout
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <ToggleButton
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/toggleButton1"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="@drawable/switch_icon"
            android:text=""
            android:textOff=""
            android:textOn=""/>

        <ToggleButton
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/toggleButton2"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="@drawable/switch_icon"
            android:text=""
            android:textOff=""
            android:textOn=""/>

        <ToggleButton
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/toggleButton3"
            android:layout_weight="6"
            android:background="@drawable/switch_icon"
            android:text=""
            android:textOff=""
            android:textOn=""/>

    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <ToggleButton
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/toggleButton4"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="@drawable/switch_icon"
            android:text=""
            android:textOff=""
            android:textOn=""/>

        <ToggleButton
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/toggleButton5"
            android:layout_weight="2"
            android:background="@drawable/switch_icon"
            android:text=""
            android:textOff=""
            android:textOn=""/>

        <ToggleButton
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/toggleButton6"
            android:layout_weight="3"
            android:background="@drawable/switch_icon"
            android:text=""
            android:textOff=""
            android:textOn=""
            />
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <ToggleButton
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/toggleButton7"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="@drawable/switch_icon"
            android:text=""
            android:textOff=""
            android:textOn=""/>

        <ToggleButton
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/toggleButton8"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="@drawable/switch_icon"
            android:text=""
            android:textOff=""
            android:textOn=""/>

        <ToggleButton
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/toggleButton9"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="@drawable/switch_icon"
            android:text=""
            android:textOff=""
            android:textOn=""/>
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <TextView
            android:text="score"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/score"
            android:layout_weight="1" />

        <TextView
            android:text="time"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/time"
            android:layout_weight="1" />
    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pode indicar o estado de *checked/unchecked* do *ToggleButton*, via *java*, usando o método [setChecked()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ToggleButton.html#setChecked(boolean)).

O estado *enabled/disabled* é indicado através do método [setEnabled()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#setEnabled(boolean)).

Ambos os métodos recebem um *boolean*:

- `true` para *checked/enabled*
- `false` para *unchecked/disabled*